# Clion Intel C++ compiler setup

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, intel, clion

Clion does not officially support Intel C++ compiler but I found the information that it suppose to work. I am just not sure how to correctly setup the toolchain. At the moment I am successfully using the clang compiler. Simply changing to icc compiler fails to compile a simple test program. Unfortunately I could not find any more guidance about setting up the icc compiler on Clion, could someone more experienced to share some insights?

Currently:
[image: Clang]

Want to use intel c++:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021-12-06

From 2021.3, you can use a System toolchain for this.

1. Set environment variable `VS2019INSTALLDIR` or `VS2017INSTALLDIR`
2. Create a System toolchain in CLion
3. Add environment from file `%ONEAPI_ROOT%\compiler\latest\env\vars.bat`
4. Set MKake as `nmake`, C Compiler and C++ Compiler as `icx`

Note that you can't use `icl`, as cmake will fail when getting compiler information.

---

Original answer

You need to edit some environment variables.

1. Add `%ICPP_COMPILER20%bin\intel64` to `PATH`
2. Add `%ICPP_COMPILER20%compiler\lib\intel64` to `LIB`; but mostly `LIB` does not exist, so create this variable

You may need to modify the `20` in `%ICPP_COMPILER20%` to match your installation.

With the above steps, you should be able to pass the compiler check. However, CLion will complain "Unexpected compiler output".
This means you can compile your program with no issue, but the IDE can't recognize any header file and simply marks them as "not found".

Answer (score 0):

I am using cygwin compiler (make, gdb, gcc, g++) GNU Project. I am specifying Clion's path to cygwin (gcc, cmake, make, g++) in File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchain. [Click me - image settings Clion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDCj3.png)